# Nothing showing on screen. Just showing a list of items from a collection

Tags: meteor, reactjs

Im holding non persistant data , calling an api (Meteor.method) Its supposed to show a list of items(text)but nothing is showing up on screen

```
if(Meteor.isClient) {
   Searches = new Meteor.Collection('searches');
   Meteor.subscribe('allSearches');
   console.log(Searches.find());
}
```

...

```
    renderTasks(){
   return this.data.searches.map((searches, i) => {
      return <SearchResultItem key={i} searches={searches} />;
    });
 },
```

...

```
 <ul>
    {this.renderTasks()}
 </ul>
```

...

```
SearchResultItem = React.createClass({
  render(){
    return
      <li >
         {this.props.searches}
      </li>
      }
});
```

Comment: If you are using an ES6 transpiler, try putting braces around the return result when it is multiline - `SearchResultItem = React.createClass({
  render(){
    return(
      <li >
         {this.props.searches}
      </li>);
      }
});`

Comment: Youre not putting anything in either state or props when getting the result back from your API.

Comment: what's `this.data.searches` supposed to be?